# Is it true that for every sequence $(a_n)$ either $\lim_{n\to \infty} na_n \neq 1$ or $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^2a_n \neq 1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Is it true that for every sequence $(a_n)$ either $\lim_{n\to \infty} na_n \neq 1$ or $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^2a_n \neq 1$ ?

Just a question I wonder about.

Comment: As long as your not equal signs are true when the limit does not exist, it is true.  It could be that both limits fail to exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\lim_{n \to \infty} n a_n = 1$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 a_n = \infty$.

If $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 a_n = 1$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} n a_n = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

It is true. If $\lim na_n\neq 1$ you are done. If  $\lim na_n= 1$, then, note that $n^2a_n=n(na_n)$, so $\lim n^2a_n=\infty$, in particular $\lim n^2a_n\neq 1$.

More or less this is telling you that $a_n$ cannot behave as $1/n$ and $1/n^2$ at the same time since these two have different growth rates.